# Having event messages to OpenLog in a summarized version

Tags: java, xpages

I am evaluating to use the Openlog Logger in my XPages application [https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger] but I notice that each time I call Openlog.LogEvent method that the message is stored in a separate Notes document entry.

I have a lot of debug statements which I would like to capture but more in a summary document, not individual documents.

Loading a page in my application can display multiple objects via MVC so loading page can lead to a large number of event logging calls...

Answer (score 1):

Collect your messages in a global string variable or a scope variable and call Openlog.LogEvent at the end with the collected messages as parameter.

Comment: I'm already ahead of you there ;-) https://stash.openntf.org/projects/OPENLOG/repos/xpages-openlog-logger/browse/OpenLogOSGi/com.paulwithers.openLog/src/com/paulwithers/openLog/OpenLogItem.java#1256

Comment: Hmmm. I would expect it to split the string to additional RT paragraphs. Your solution causes loss of data, in my opinion. Coder should be aware of that.

Comment: No, it stores the full message in LogDocInfo, the first 100 chars + "..." in the LogMessage field that displays in the view. So you still get the full message, but don't get masses displayed in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Each message has a different stack trace. If you have a message in a central function, it can be useful to know what the stack trace was that triggered that message. I've often found that useful when I couldn't work out why a piece of code got triggered. If they're aggregated, the stack trace would only be the last call.

The downside of Knut's approach is that if an error occurs before the final call to OpenLog.logEvent, nothing would get logged, which I can envisage would be problematic.

However, because OpenLog uses a PhaseListener to log everything out even if there's an error, I could add a new bean that captures debug messages and output that at the end of the lifecycle. An `OpenLogUtil` method could be used to more easily access that. However, it wouldn't be usable outside the XPages runtime.

Are you writing your debug message from Java? And can you confirm you're using the OSGi plugin version?

Obviously any additions to XPages OpenLog Logger get added at the same time to OpenNTF Domino API ;-).